# Need to change the query in the recent modified date with distinct of record ids

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Code:

```
public IList<TestGridModel> GetRecords()
{
    return _TestRepository.GetAll()
           .Select(x => new TestGridModel
           {
               IdName = x.IdName,
               LName = x.LastName,
               FName = x.FirstName,
               IdRecord = x.RecordId,
               LastModifiedDate = x.LMDate
           }).ToList();
}
```

> I need to change the above query based on the following condition.
>
> I want to fetch the records of recent modified
>   date(LastModifiedDate) with distinct of IdRecords(IdRecord).

**Note**: Record Id may be duplicate, but I need to get the records with recent modified date with distinct of record ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and then take first item from the group order by modified date.

```
_TestRepository.GetAll()
               .GroupBy(x => x.RecordId)
               .Select(g => g.OrderByDesceding(i => i.LMDate).First()})                                                      
               .Select(x => new TestGridModel
                {
                   IdName = x.Itemx.IdName,
                   LName = x.LastName,
                   FName = x.FirstName,
                   IdRecord = x.RecordId,
                   LastModifiedDate = x.LMDate
                });
```